Limited access in SharePoint List using Power Apps
To write and read data to and from my Power App I use a SharePoint List. However, the data cannot be displayed and written because the members of the list have limited access. How do I prevent and solve this so that the application and the list works as it should? The error message can be seen in the images.
I don't know if this matters, but the list has been shared with guest users, they are all experiencing the same problem. Thank you in advance!


These rights are added for the added users
:


Can you please share the access which you shared with them?

Updated the question. They all can contribute.
